# how to use Electic ip address of amazon ec2 in windows to setup DNS?

Tags: amazon-ec2

how to setup *Elastic ip* in **tacp/ip** in windows 2008 server to setup **Microsoft DNS** ?

i have Elastic ip address.. i have to set it in NIC (Tcp/Ip)

Answer (score 1):

The EC2 instance has an internal IP address and an external IP address. The external IP address is used so the outside world can find your EC2 instance.  The internal IP address is used so the internal AWS network can find your EC2 instance.

Elastic IP addresses are used to replace the external IP addresses only.

The internal IP address should not be modified and your NIC should only use the internal IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Request a new elastic IP and assign it to your instance. Leave your server set to DHCP. You may also want to look into a VPC if you are running multiple instances.